# custom ErrorHandler for SQLiteOpenHelper in sqlCipher

Tags: android, database, sqlcipher

I started using sqlCipher for Android (ver) 2.1.1 and it works like charm on Android 4.0.3. However I found that the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class does not have the constructor that takes the custom Error handler. This is very much there in the original `SQLiteOpenHelper` class provided in android.database and it is very useful to handle the errors in an app specific manner. Does anyone know how to incorporate a custom error handler when using sqlCipher?

Constructors available in **android.database.sqlite**

```
public SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version);
public SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler);
```

Constructors available in **net.sqlcipher.database**

```
public SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version);
```

In specific, when encountered with certain types of errors the default error handler (when using sqlcipher) is removing the database, albeit after providing a Log.e message. But I need to avoid it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom database error handlers are more recent additions to the android.database package. The SQLCipher packages are based on an older API (level 7), and thus don't include this feature. We'll try to take a closer look at this and see if there is something we can do to address the issue without affecting backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Any quick solution is appreciated

Comment: Cross post from mailing list:
We did a bit more research into this over the past week. Unfortunately it doesn't look like this would be a very simple change. We're still committed to supporting API Level 7 and the changes required to implement the new functionality while preserving backwards compatibi
lity would be relatively complex. As a result, while we agree that the provider's behavior of deleting corrupt databases is undesirable, we may not have a short-term fix for this. We'll continue to look into it as time permits, but I at least wanted to let you know where things stand today.

Comment: Thanks again for the prompt response. Is there a package for using cipher on Android 4.0.3 and API-15, if ver2.1.1 is for API-7?

Comment: This issue is resolved as per check in by Chris at https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/pull/84. I think it is merged into main stream now.